# Error: A factory has already been set on this LayoutInflater (change background color of menu options)

Tags: android, android-layout, background

I want to change background color of menu options. And I get **error**: 
 
`FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.IllegalStateException: A factory has already been set on this LayoutInflater
at android.view.LayoutInflater.setFactory(LayoutInflater.java:277)`

I use this **code**: 

`private void setMenuBackground() {`

```
 getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() { 
        @Override 
        public View onCreateView (String name, Context context, AttributeSet attrs) { 
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase("com.android.internal.view.menu.IconMenuItemView")) { 
            try { 

                    LayoutInflater f = getLayoutInflater(); 
                    final View view = f.createView(name, null, attrs); 

                    new Handler().post( new Runnable() { 
                        public void run () { 
                            view.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY); 
                        } 
                    }); 
                    return view; 
                } 
                catch (InflateException e) { 
                } 
                catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { 
                } 
            } 
            return null; 
        } 
    });
```

}

I find some answers but they don't help me. 
 How can I resolve this problem? Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

To keep compatibility library working and avoid "java.lang.illegalstateexception: a factory has already been set on this layoutinflater", you need to get a final reference to the already set Factory and call its onCreateView within your own Factory.onCreateView. Before that an introspection trick must be use to allow you to set one more time a Factory to the LayoutInflater :

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = getLayoutInflater();
final Factory existingFactory = layoutInflater.getFactory();
// use introspection to allow a new Factory to be set
try {
    Field field = LayoutInflater.class.getDeclaredField("mFactorySet");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.setBoolean(layoutInflater, false);
    getLayoutInflater().setFactory(new Factory() {
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(String name, final Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            View view = null;
            // if a factory was already set, we use the returned view
            if (existingFactory != null) {
                view = existingFactory.onCreateView(name, context, attrs);
            }
            // do whatever you want with the null or non-null view
            // such as expanding 'IconMenuItemView' and changing its style
            // or anything else...
            // and return the view
            return view;
        }
    });
} catch (NoSuchFieldException e) {
    // ...
} catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
    // ...
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try

```
LayoutInfalter inflater = getLayoutInflater.cloneInContext(this);
```

and then do what you need with your cloned layout

But I do not know if your onCreateView will ever be executed in that way